# How do I start the index array after 1 in an ionic 4 App sqlite db

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic4, ionic-storage

I am looping thought the the sqlite db with ionic storage using this code

ts

```
listKeys() {
  this.storage.keys().then((k) => {
    console.table(k);
    this.loop = k;
    console.log("key value", this.loop);
  });
}
```

Here is what I get

[image: list of keys]

I use this html to view my list

```
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let list of loop; index as i ">
    <ion-item>
        {{loop[i]}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="end">
      <ion-item-option (click)="deleteKeyValue( loop[i] )" color="danger">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
```

I wish to start the loop after Index 1.  I have tried "index as i  > 1 " and loop[ i > 1 ].  of course neither work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SlicePipe https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

`<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let list of loop | slice:2; index as i ">`

Comment: This may sound weird but that goes to the back of the list starts slicing Index 3 and 4

Comment: Your answer is completely correct.  My issue is that I getting my array from a key and I had get {{loop[i]}} to view a list of keys and be able to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code after implementing the answer and correcting my issues with looping.

```
<ion-list lines="inset">
  <ion-item-divider>
    <ion-label>
      List of Audits
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item-divider>
 <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let i of loop | slice:2">
    <ion-item>
        {{i}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="end">
      <ion-item-option (click)="deleteKeyValue( i )" color="danger">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```